# pandas: plot multiple columns of a timeseries with labels.

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas

I am new in python and panda.I am trying to draw graph using python panda. So far i am able to read sqlite database.

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd


conn = sqlite3.connect('demo.db')
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM ABC", conn)
df.head()
```

I get this output as result. [image]

Here time stamp is for only single year. I want to plot line graph (Year vs Value) for all Type.

Thanks for help

Comment: You're a bit away from generating a plot, you need to convert your timestamp into a datetime first

Comment: @EdChum Thank you for your comment. I am not sure how can i convert in panda. Can you help me out to plot graph ?

Comment: `import datetime as dt` `df['DateTime'] = df['TimeStamp'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(x))`

Comment: Once it's a datetime you then have to decide whether to groupby the year or create a new year column but your details are pretty vague at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Without converting timestamp to datetime you just do a plot call

```
from pylab import *
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3 

# load in your dataframe viy current code
conn = sqlite3.connect('demo.db')
df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM ABC',conn)

# make your plot
fig = figure( figsize=(6.5,3.5) )
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(df.TimeStamp, df.Value)
ax.legend( ('Value') )
```

Now the real question is what are you doing with your timestamp?  EdChum already explained how to convert to datetime, but looking at your data I see that you have only one unique TimeStamp value, so if your x-axis is time you will have everything stacked on top of the rest.  However, if you really want a time vs. value plot (you indicated this, but I assumed you mis-typed) then this would make more sense and you will need to switch df.TimeStamp and df.Value in the ax.plot command above.

Comment: I want Month vs Value. so i need to extract month from time stamp

Comment: Fine, once you change your index to datetime values just do a resample: df = df.resample(rule='1M',how='mean')

Comment: I am not able to plot graph with given code                                              # make your plot
fig = figure( figsize=(6.5,3.5) )
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(df.Timestamp, df.Value)
ax.legend( ('Value') )
plt.savefig('EU2.png', bbox_inches='tight')

Comment: I am getting something like this which is not my desiered output. I want Graph for Line 1 and Line 2 where x axis =  Month and y axis = Value                                http://postimg.org/image/5m4yfnk8z/

Comment: That looks exactly as I expected since all of your time stamps are the same.  Looks right to me, your data are wrong.

Comment: I tested with different time stamp, still it did not work. I use this data frame http://postimg.org/image/4tw1d81vh/